# Python, tkinter: How to change color of button on press?

Tags: python, tkinter

Ok, so I have this code that generates a grid of buttons:

```
def click():

    squares[-1][y].configure(bg='blue')

def game(width,height):

    global squares
    squares = []

    global y

    for x in range(width):

        squares.append([0] * height)

        for y in range(height):

            squares[-1][y] = Button(gameWindow,command=click)
            squares[-1][y].grid(column = x, row = (y + 1), sticky =(N+S+E+W))

    for x in range(width):

        Grid.columnconfigure(gameWindow, x, weight = 1)

    for y in range(height):

        Grid.rowconfigure(gameWindow, (y + 1), weight = 1)

    gameWindow.mainloop()

game(8,8)
```

I can configure a specific button (1,1) by doing this:

```
squares[1][1].configure(bg='blue')
```

But when I try to configure a button when it is used, it changes the button in the bottom right.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Specifically: what happens and what you expected to happen.

Comment: you have `for y in range(height)` so after this loop `y == height-1`.  And you do `squares[-1][y].configure(bg='blue')` so you use `squares[-1][height-1]`

Comment: you need `Button(gameWindow, command=lambda arg=y:click(arg))` and `def click(arg): squares[-1][arg].config(bg='blue')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change button color with tkinter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543815/how-to-change-button-color-with-tkinter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have loop

```
for y in range(height):
```

so after this loop `y` is equal `height-1`.

When you click button then it uses `squares[-1][y]` but `y = height-1` so you use always `squares[-1][height-1]`

You have to assing to button function with argument - button number - using `lambda`.
But if you use `lambda` inside `for` then you can't do directly `lambda:click(y)`
but you need `lambda arg=y:click(arg)`

```
 Button(gameWindow, command=lambda arg=y:click(arg))
```

And function has to get this argument and use it

```
 def click(arg): 
      squares[-1][arg].config(bg='blue')
```